# Memory consumption overhead on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, memory-management, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

Universal Windows 8.1 Store project here.

I'm doing a bit of memory profiling on emulator with 512mb of memory. The test I'm talking here about is not exactly practical, I'm just trying to understand the mechanics.

The test project is very simple: it opens a big file (over 700mb) for sequential reading on a thread and reads it through a 15mb buffer, doing a `await Task.Delay();` after each iteration, to keep the thread running longer. I launch the same code several times with `Task.Run()` and observe memory consumption.

When I force the GC, the amount of memory is close to what I would expect:

```
some initial 6-7 mb + 
number_of_tasks * buffer_size + 
some little memory per task for the objects created by the reading method
```

But what puzzles me is the initial memory overhead when I start the tasks. Before the GC is triggered, the app consumes twice as much memory, thus I get out of memory exception for only 6 simultaneous reading threads.

For example, when I have 5 reading threads:

- the app starts with `~6.5mb` of memory,
- then it increases to `~175mb`, when the tasks are created (**why?**)
- when a snapshot is taken (triggering the GC), consumption drops to `~85mb`
- when all threads finish reading, memory drops to `~10mb`

[image]

What happens there? Am I just doing something wrong?

Here's a brief version of the code I use for the test:

```
// the code is placed in the only page of the default Universal App -> Blank App template
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
  Test();
}

async Task Test()
{
    Debug.WriteLine("BEGIN");
    var task1 = Task.Run(()=>ReadFile("1"));
    var task2 = Task.Run(()=>ReadFile("2"));
    var task3 = Task.Run(()=>ReadFile("3"));
    var task4 = Task.Run(()=>ReadFile("4"));
    var task5 = Task.Run(()=>ReadFile("5"));
    Debug.WriteLine("END");

    await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2, task3, task4, task5, task6);

    Debug.WriteLine("ALL TASKS COMPLETE");
}

async Task ReadFile(string tag)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("FILE {0}: begin", tag);
    var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(
        new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/test.rar")
    );      
    using(var seqStream = await file.OpenSequentialReadAsync()) {
        var buf = CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(new byte[15*1024*1024]);
        IBuffer result = null;
        uint total = 0;
        do {
            Debug.WriteLine("FILE {0}: read {1} bytes", tag, buf.Length);
            var operation = seqStream.ReadAsync(buf, buf.Capacity, InputStreamOptions.None);
            await operation;
            if (operation.Status == AsyncStatus.Completed) {
                result = operation.GetResults();
                total += result.Length;
                Debug.WriteLine("FILE {0}: got {1} bytes", tag, total);
            } else {
                result = null;
            }
            await Task.Delay(234);
        } while (result != null && result.Length == buf.Capacity);
    }
    Debug.WriteLine("FILE {0}: end", tag);
}
```

**UPDATE**: I found out, that when I don't use thread pool and just do `var task1 = ReadFile("1");`, the memory overhead gets some 5 times lower (albeit it's still there). Why's that? (In the real project I have some cpu-bound work on the file contents, and not just asynchronous IO, so I guess I'll need separate threads for that anyway.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in CryptographicBuffer. Windows.Storage.Streams.Buffer should be used for file IO.

```
var buf = new Windows.Storage.Streams.Buffer(16*1024);
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunatelly, this does not answer my question.

Comment: Does application consume more then 20-30mb after you reduce buffer size?

Comment: It doesn't. The question is: why? I get better results without thread pool and with a small buffer I don't get much overhead at all. Why is this happening?

Comment: I initially chose large buffer just to be able to see the impact with a small number of concurrent reads.

Comment: The only problem was in a huge buffer (15mb). For every file/task you created 15 mb buffer and it was collected by GC when task finished.

Comment: **Naturally** huge buffer increases memory consumption. What I don't understand is why memory jumps up twice the expected amount at the begining.

Comment: Maybe the problem in CryptographicBuffer. Try use `var buf =  new Windows.Storage.Streams.Buffer(16*1024);`

Comment: Oh, shi... You are right there! Without `CryptographicBuffer` the problem is gone completely, what with thread pool or without it. Please, update your answer and I will accept it.